# Jbutton cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jbutton

So basically I have everything declared but somehow they still failed to be resolved as a type. Any ideas?
[JAVA screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pNez.png)

```
JRadioButton englishRadio = new JRadioButton("English");
    englishRadio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            if(englishRadio.isSelected())
            {
                mathRadio.setSelected(false);
                historyRadio.setSelected(false);

            }
        }
    });
    englishRadio.setBounds(6, 17, 70, 23);
    PreferredSubjects.add(englishRadio);

    JRadioButton mathRadio = new JRadioButton("Math");
    mathRadio.setBounds(6, 43, 70, 23);
    PreferredSubjects.add(mathRadio);

    JRadioButton historyRadio = new JRadioButton("History");
    historyRadio.setBounds(6, 67, 70, 23);
    PreferredSubjects.add(historyRadio);
```

Comment: Please include the code as *text*, not an image.

Comment: Make those variables instance fields. Or at least declare them as *final* variables **before** you use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference an object until *after* it is declared, unless of course it is a field. Try moving your declaration *above* your action listener:

```
    // Declare mathRadio before you create englishRadio's actionListener.
    JRadioButton mathRadio = new JRadioButton("Math");
    mathRadio.setBounds(6, 43, 70, 23);
    PreferredSubjects.add(mathRadio);

    // Declare historyRadio before you create englishRadio's actionListener.
    JRadioButton historyRadio = new JRadioButton("History");
    historyRadio.setBounds(6, 67, 70, 23);
    PreferredSubjects.add(historyRadio);

    // Declare englishRadio before you assign it an actionListener.
    JRadioButton englishRadio = new JRadioButton("English");
    // Create the actionListener after declaring your three radios.
    englishRadio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            if(englishRadio.isSelected())
            {
                mathRadio.setSelected(false);
                historyRadio.setSelected(false);

            }
        }
    });
    englishRadio.setBounds(6, 17, 70, 23);
    PreferredSubjects.add(englishRadio);
```

You might also want to look at Oracle's tutorial for [Creating Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)
 and [Using Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html). If you are unfamiliar with how fields work, there is another tutorial you will find quite handy: [Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)